# Too many objects getting created while creating shapes in html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm creating a simple paint app in html5 canvas and JavaScript which creates triangles of variable size. I have just figured out how to do this and am now trying to drag and move the triangles that have been created. For this, I'm using a "triangles" array to store all the triangle objects.

When I try to push one object of one triangle into the array, too many objects get created. How do I fix this?  I just want one object per triangle.

My code:
**HTML:**

```
<body>
        <h1>Simple Paint App</h1>
        <div id="canvs">
            <canvas id="paint-canvas" width="800" height="400"></canvas>
            <button id="buttn" >Clear/Reset</button>
        </div>
        
        <noscript>This site requires JavaScript to be activated.</noscript>
    </body>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
let canvas = document.querySelector("#paint-canvas");
let context = canvas.getContext("2d");

let triangles = []

let offsetX = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
let offsetY = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;
let startX, startY;
let dragOk = false;
let imageData;

function getCoordinates(e){
    const X = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    const Y = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
    
    return {x: X, y: Y};
}

function getRandomColor(){
    const colors = 
    ["#DFFF00", "#FFBF00", "#FF7F50", "#DE3163", "#9FE2BF", "#40E0D0", "#6495ED", "#CCCCFF"];
    return colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
}

canvas.onmousedown = mouseDown;
canvas.onmouseup = mouseUp;
canvas.onmousemove = mouseMove;
document.querySelector("#buttn").addEventListener("click", () => resetCanvas());


function mouseDown(e){
    dragOk = true;
    const start = getCoordinates(e);
    startX = start.x;
    startY = start.y;
    storeImageData();
}

function mouseUp(e){
    dragOk = false;
    restoreImageData();
    let position = getCoordinates(e);
    drawTriangle(position);
    console.log(triangles);
}

function mouseMove(e){
    if (!dragOk) {
        return;
    }
    let position;
    restoreImageData()
    position = getCoordinates(e);
    drawTriangle(position);
}

function storeImageData() {
    imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function restoreImageData() {
    context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}

function drawTriangle(position) {
    let tri = { x:startX, y:startY, points: [{x:0,y:0},{x:0,y:0},{x:0,y:0}], outline: "#000000", fill:"#000000", dragOk: false };

    const radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((startX - position.x), 2) + Math.pow((startY - position.y), 2));
    let i = 0;
    let angle = 100;
    // 3 because triangle has 3 sides
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        tri.points[i].x = startX + radius * Math.cos(angle);
        tri.points[i].y = startY - radius * Math.sin(angle);        
        angle += (2 * Math.PI) / 3;
    }

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(tri.points[0].x, tri.points[0].y);

    for (i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
        context.lineTo(tri.points[i].x, tri.points[i].y);
    }

    context.closePath();

    // the outline
    context.lineWidth = 5;
    tri.outline = "#000000"
    context.strokeStyle = tri.outline;
    context.stroke();

    // the fill color
    tri.fill = getRandomColor();
    context.fillStyle = tri.fill;
    context.fill();
    triangles.push(tri)
}

function resetCanvas() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

Edit:
I am pushing the newly created triangles in the drawTriangle function.
JSFiddle: [Code](https://jsfiddle.net/drepkn/nrsyetdu/3/)

Comment: JS programming note: make that `<script src="js/paint.js" async defer></script>` and put in in the `<head>` element. It's not 1998 anymore, add `async` so your script loads off of the main tread, without blocking anything, and `defer` so it runs only after the DOM is ready for access. Also, don't use `onclick="resetCanvas()", put that logic in your paint.js: find the button with id `buttn` and use `addEventListener("click", () => resetCanvas())`. Finally, you are **not** storing JSON, you're storing regular objects. JSON is string data. Important to get terms right.

Comment: I should have done that first. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your **drawTriangle** function is chained to the `onMouseMove` event. Of course this event is required to size the triangles but you shouldn't use it to stuff objects inside the **triangles** array, as this means as long as the mouse is moving, your creating new objects which are pushed into the array.

Better do it like this:

- create a global variable `tempTriangle`
- inside the drawTriangle function assign `tri` to `tempTriangle`
- if the mouse button is released push `tempTriangle` into the `triangles` array

Here's an example based on your code:

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector("#paint-canvas");
let context = canvas.getContext("2d");

let triangles = []

let offsetX = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
let offsetY = canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;
let startX, startY;
let dragOk = false;
let imageData;
let tempTriangle;

function getCoordinates(e) {
  const X = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
  const Y = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

  return {
    x: X,
    y: Y
  };
}

function getRandomColor() {
  const colors = ["#DFFF00", "#FFBF00", "#FF7F50", "#DE3163", "#9FE2BF", "#40E0D0", "#6495ED", "#CCCCFF"];
  return colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
}

canvas.onmousedown = mouseDown;
canvas.onmouseup = mouseUp;
canvas.onmousemove = mouseMove;


function mouseDown(e) {
  dragOk = true;
  const start = getCoordinates(e);
  startX = start.x;
  startY = start.y;
  storeImageData();
}

function mouseUp(e) {
  dragOk = false;
  restoreImageData();
  let position = getCoordinates(e);
  drawTriangle(position);
  triangles.push(tempTriangle)
  console.log(triangles, triangles.length);
}

function mouseMove(e) {
  if (!dragOk) {
    return;
  }
  let position;
  restoreImageData()
  position = getCoordinates(e);
  drawTriangle(position);
}

function storeImageData() {
  imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function restoreImageData() {
  context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}

function drawTriangle(position) {
  let tri = {
    x: startX,
    y: startY,
    points: [{
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    }, {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    }, {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    }],
    outline: "#000000",
    fill: "#000000",
    dragOk: false
  };

  const radius = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((startX - position.x), 2) + Math.pow((startY - position.y), 2));
  let i = 0;
  let angle = 100;
  // 3 because triangle has 3 sides
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    tri.points[i].x = startX + radius * Math.cos(angle);
    tri.points[i].y = startY - radius * Math.sin(angle);
    angle += (2 * Math.PI) / 3;
  }

  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(tri.points[0].x, tri.points[0].y);

  for (i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
    context.lineTo(tri.points[i].x, tri.points[i].y);
  }

  context.closePath();

  // the outline
  context.lineWidth = 5;
  tri.outline = "#000000"
  context.strokeStyle = tri.outline;
  context.stroke();

  // the fill color
  tri.fill = getRandomColor();
  context.fillStyle = tri.fill;
  context.fill();
  tempTriangle = tri;

}

function resetCanvas() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');
h1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

#paint-canvas {
  border: 1vh solid black;
}

#canvs {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#buttn {
  margin: 5vh 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvs">
  <canvas id="paint-canvas" width="800" height="400"></canvas>
  <button id="buttn" onclick="resetCanvas()">Clear/Reset</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: No problem Mohnish - glad I could help! =)